# Return ONE Row For EmpName

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

My tables may or may not have the same employee Names listed in them.  The problem is I have no way of knowing if Table1 will hold more names or if Table2 will hold more names so I was thinking a union would solve this issue.  However as you see in the syntax below it produces to lines for "C" since it exists in both tables.  This is my desired output

```
empName | TotalSW | TotalSNT  
--------+---------+---------
A       |       1 |       0
B       |       1 |       0
C       |       1 |       1
x       |       0 |       1
z       |       0 |       1
```

With the DDL Below how can a query be written to produce this output?

```
Create Table #Test1
(empName varchar(100), swas varchar(100))

Create Table #Test2
(empName varchar(100), swont varchar(100))

Insert Into #Test1 (empName, swas) VALUES
('A', 'res1'), ('B', 'tim1'), ('C', 'run34')

Insert Into #Test2 (empName, swont) VALUES
('C', 'er12'), ('z', 'nn12'), ('x', '23rw')


Select empName, TotalSW = COUNT(swas), TotalSNT = ''
FROM #Test1
GROUP BY empName
Union 
Select empName, TotalSW = '', TotalSNT = Count(swont)
FROM #Test2
GROUP BY empName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and dirty method is to just wrap your query in another aggregation.

```
SELECT   x.empName, SUM(x.TotalSW), SUM(x.TotalSNT)
FROM     (
             SELECT   empName, COUNT(swas) AS TotalSW, 0 AS TotalSNT
             FROM     #Test1
             GROUP BY empName
             UNION ALL
             SELECT   empName, 0 AS TotalSW, COUNT(swont) AS TotalSNT
             FROM     #Test2
             GROUP BY empName ) AS x
GROUP BY x.empName;
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. You could use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which will pull data:

```
SELECT ISNULL(#Test1.empName, #Test2.empName)
     , TotalSW  = COUNT(#Test1.empName)
     , TotalSNT = COUNT(#Test2.empName)
FROM #Test1 
FULL OUTER JOIN #Test2 ON #Test2.empName = #Test1.EmpName
GROUP BY ISNULL(#Test1.empName, #Test2.empName)
```

<sub>(NOTE: the previous example that used `SUM` over a `CASE` statement isn't needed as `COUNT` does not count `NULL` values which is what the extra jiggery-pokery was trying to do)</sub>

or to keep the `UNION` method (which may be more or less efficient in more complex examples depending on the rest of the query):

```
SELECT empName, TotalSW = SUM(TotalSW), SUM(TotalSNT)
FROM   (
        SELECT empName, TotalSW = 1, TotalSNT = 0
        FROM #Test1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT empName, TotalSW = 0, TotalSNT = 1
        FROM #Test2
        ) AS sq
GROUP BY empName
```

Note the use of `UNION ALL` not just `UNION` - otherwise it will filter out duplicates if an employee exists more than once in one table. `UNION ALL` is also often more efficient because it possibly avoids extra sort operations so unless you *need* duplicate removal you should use it instead of plain `UNION`.

Or if you find the CTE syntax more readable than sub-queries (which it often is in more complex examples, though it makes no difference here IMO):

```
WITH Emps AS (
        SELECT empName, TotalSW = 1, TotalSNT = 0
        FROM #Test1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT empName, TotalSW = 0, TotalSNT = 1
        FROM #Test2
        )
SELECT empName, TotalSW = SUM(TotalSW), SUM(TotalSNT)
FROM   Emps
GROUP BY empName
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
select empName, count(swas), count(swont)
from (
    select empName, swas, null as swont
    from #Test1
    union
    select empName, null as swas, swont
    from #Test2
    ) t
group by empName
```

Comment: You need to use `SUM` here, `COUNT` double-counts the values for employee C when you aggregate.

Comment: Also you want `UNION ALL` if there might be duplicates to count in each table. Plain `UNION` implies `DISTINCT` so would merge such duplicates. `UNION ALL` is often more efficient too as it avoids potentially needing extra sort operations needed to find the duplicates.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik: count is ok since it counts not null values, so for employee C we only have one line, as asked in the question.

Comment: @irimias but the count is wrong.